# Agregar boton editar en table php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

hace poco vengo aprendiendo php con mysql y vengo a solicitar ayuda ya que necesito agregar un boton editar a mi tabla que es la siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde dice opciones necesito agregar un href llamado dar reporte para editar el registro pasando 3 variables en este caso ID, estado y comentario, este es el codigo que estoy utilizando

```
<?php
                        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM mensaje WHERE destinatario='$usuarioingresado'";
                        $ejecutarConsulta = mysqli_query($mysqli, $consulta);
                        $verFilas = mysqli_num_rows($ejecutarConsulta);
                        $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutarConsulta);

                        if(!$ejecutarConsulta){
                            echo"Error en la consulta";
                        }else{
                            if($verFilas<1){
                                echo"<tr><td>Sin registros</td></tr>";
                            }else{
                                for($i=0; $i<=$fila; $i++){
                  {
                    $fila6_color = array(
                        'En desarrollo' => '#ECF705',
                        'Finalizada' => '#15D50F',
                        'No Realizada' => '#EF0E0E'
                    );
                  }
                  echo "<tr ".(isset( $fila[6] ) && isset( $fila6_color[$fila[6]] ) ? 'bgcolor="'.$fila6_color[$fila[6]].'"' : '').">
                  <td>".$fila[0]."</td>
                  <td>".$fila[1]."</td>
                  <td>".$fila[2]."</td>
                  <td>".$fila[3]."</td>
                  <td>".$fila[4]."</td>
                  <td>".$fila[5]."</td>
                  <td>".$fila[6]."</td>
                  <td>".$fila[7]."</td>
                  <td>".$fila[8]."</td>
                  <td>
                  
                  
                              </tr>";
                              $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutarConsulta);
                        }
                      }
                  }
                  ?>              
                      </table>
                  </div>
```

Intente utilizar este codigo luego de la fila 8, pero me mandaba error

```
<td><a href="editartareas.php?id=<?php echo $fila[8] ?> &
          estado=<?php echo $fila[6] ?> &
          comentario=<?php echo $fila[7] ?>
">Dar Reporte</a></td>
```

Si es posible darme una mano porfavor, Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Las comillas del valor de `href` cierran y re-abren las comillas del `echo`, prueba con comillas sencillas: `<a href='editartareas.php...'>`

Comment: Además, cuando haces `echo` no funciona `<?php echo >`. Estas mezclando mal las  sintaxis.

Comment: Prueba con esto: `<td><a href=\"editartareas.php?id=".$fila[8]."&estado=".$fila[6]."&comentario=".$fila[7]."\">Dar Reporte</a></td>`

Comment: Exacto... una forma de resolverlo es lo que indica @masterguru (todo con un `echo` de comillas dobles, tal y como está, pero vigilando los espacios en blanco que te sobraban en tu código, también.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigos me ha funcionado, saludos que se encuentren bien